# Partially-rendered UITableView header

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am populating a `UITableView` from an array - lets call it `sections`. The `numberOfSectionsInTableView` returns `sections.count`, except for a special case - if `sections.count` is 0, I return 1 (1 is the minimum number of sections that should ever be returned by `numberOfSectionsInTableView`). I return `nil` as the section header in this case, so the `UITableView` looks empty.

When a new item is added to my `dataSource`, I manually insert a new row. I also check if a new section is required, and if so I add it to `sections` and insert the new section. But here is where my 'special case' causes problems.

When adding the first item, to the first section, I don't want to add a new section (because there is already one section minimum at all times). So, I just insert the row.

The row animation insertion seems correct, but I get a strange half-loaded header:

[image]

All I really need to do is make the `UITableView` reload the header when the first row is inserted. But I don't want to lose the insertion animations by simply reloading the tableview or the section.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for [`-reloadSections:withRowAnimation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadSections%3awithRowAnimation%3a).

After you add or remove the special case of section 0, you can call:

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Dangit - I was sure I had tried that (I even mentioned it in my question). Anyway, thanks.